# Forcing new line after item number in enumerate environment

Tags: lists, line-breaking, enumerate

How can I force the text of an `enumerate` item to start on a new line below the item number?

Comment: Usually ``\item\mbox{}\\`` suffices.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept answers to your questions by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count, if their respective problems have been solved. (If not, edit the question to clarify what you're looking for.) This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Answer (score 26):

As egreg mentioned in a comment, using

```
\item\mbox{}\\
```

will do the job. If you want to have the job done for you automatically, you could define a command behaving like `\item`, but adding the `\mbox{}\\`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\myitem{%
   \@ifnextchar[ \@myitem{\@noitemargtrue\@myitem[\@itemlabel]}}
\def\@myitem[#1]{\item[#1]\mbox{}\\}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item\mbox{}\\First.
  \item\mbox{}\\Second.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
  \myitem First.
  \myitem Second.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you additionally want the item text to start left aligned with the item label, you can use the `enumitem` package to define a new list which behaves like a standard `enumerate`, but with left aligned labels; and a modification to the `\myitem` command from above will be necessary:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\def\myitem{%
   \@ifnextchar[ \@myitem{\@noitemargtrue\@myitem[\@itemlabel]}}
\def\@myitem[#1]{\item[#1]\mbox{}\\\hspace*{\dimexpr-\labelwidth-\labelsep}}
\makeatother

\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[mylist,1]{align=left,label=\arabic*.}
\setlist[mylist,2]{align=left,label=(\alph*)}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}
  \myitem First item.
  \myitem Second item.
  \begin{mylist}
    \myitem First subitem.
    \myitem Second subitem.
  \end{mylist}
  \myitem Third item.
\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would probably use e.g. `\widowpenalty=10000` in such lists to prevent a page break directly after the number.

Comment: This only left-align the first line. It's better to use `leftmargin=0pt,labelwidth=*` in list options instead of `\hspace*{\dimexpr-\labelwidth-\labelsep}`.