# A step by step environment

Tags: formatting, lists, enumitem

I would like to obtain the following output :

```
Bla, bla, here are the actions to do.

    Action 1
        Bla, bla, bla...

    Action 2
        Bla, bla, bla...

    Action 3
        Bla, bla, bla...

When the preceding actions have been done, you must do the following things.

    Thing 1
        Bla, bla, bla...

    Thing 2
        Bla, bla, bla...

    Thing 3
        Bla, bla, bla...
```

The LaTeX code could look like :

```
Bla, bla, here are the actions to do.

\begin[Action]{step}
    \step
    Bla, bla, bla...

    \step
    Bla, bla, bla...

    \step
    Bla, bla, bla...
\end{step}

When the preceding actions have been done, you must do the following things.

\begin[Thing]{step}
    \step
    Bla, bla, bla...

    \step
    Bla, bla, bla...

    \step
    Bla, bla, bla...
\end{step}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `\newenvironment` to make a step by step environment, `steps`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{steps}[1]{\begin{enumerate}[label=#1 \arabic*]}{\end{enumerate}}

\makeatletter% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29517/forcing-new-line-after-item-number-in-enumerate-environment/29518#29518
\def\step{%
   \@ifnextchar[ \@step{\@noitemargtrue\@step[\@itemlabel]}}
\def\@step[#1]{\item[#1]\mbox{}\\\hspace*{\dimexpr-\labelwidth-\labelsep}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{steps}{Action}
\step Bla, bla, bla...
\step Bla, bla, bla...
\step Bla, bla, bla...
\end{steps}

\begin{steps}{Thing}
\step Bla, bla, bla...
\step Bla, bla, bla...
\step Bla, bla, bla...
\end{steps}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

To further refine this approach you can declare the environment using the LaTeX3 function `\DeclareDocumentEnvironment`. It lets you specify optional arguments and set defaults for them. The following declares a new environment, `steps`, which if it's not given any argument defaults to the label "Steps":

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{steps}%
{O{Step}}% If no argument is given the label defaults to 'Step'
{\begin{enumerate}[label=#1 \arabic*]}%
{\end{enumerate}}

\makeatletter% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29517/forcing-new-line-after-item-number-in-enumerate-environment/29518#29518
\def\step{%
   \@ifnextchar[ \@step{\@noitemargtrue\@step[\@itemlabel]}}
\def\@step[#1]{\item[#1]\mbox{}\\\hspace*{\dimexpr-\labelwidth-\labelsep}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{steps}
\step Bla, bla, bla...
\step Bla, bla, bla...
\step Bla, bla, bla...
\end{steps}

\begin{steps}[Action]
\step Bla, bla, bla...
\step Bla, bla, bla...
\step Bla, bla, bla...
\end{steps}

\begin{steps}[Thing]
\step Bla, bla, bla...
\step Bla, bla, bla...
\step Bla, bla, bla...
\end{steps}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: @projetmbc I've updated my answer to include a solution with optional arguments that can have defaults, e.g. see how it produces "Steps 1, Step 2, Step 3" when the environment `steps` is given no argument.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was playng with this... You've been faster than me...

Comment: @projetmbc If you come up anything significant your should post it as an answer (i.e. I'm curious!).

Comment: This is similar to the previous answer so no reason to post it...

Answer (score 7):

Use [the `enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem) create the label for each **Action** line item:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=Action \arabic*,align=left, leftmargin=2.0cm]
```

Since you wanted a new line after the beginning of the list I have used the solution from [Forcing new line after item number in enumerate environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29517/forcing-new-line-after-item-number-in-enumerate-environment) to define `\step`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\step{%
   \@ifnextchar[ \@myitem{\@noitemargtrue\@myitem[\@itemlabel]}}
\def\@myitem[#1]{\item[#1]\mbox{}\\}
\makeatother
```

Using these yields the desired results:

[image]

You can also use a custom environment for each section:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% Since you want a blank line after the begin of a list
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29517/forcing-new-line-after-item-number-in-enumerate-environment
\makeatletter
\def\step{%
   \@ifnextchar[ \@myitem{\@noitemargtrue\@myitem[\@itemlabel]}}
\def\@myitem[#1]{\item[#1]\mbox{}\\}
\makeatother


% Custom environments
\newenvironment{Action}{%
    \begin{enumerate}[label=Action \arabic*,align=left, leftmargin=2.0cm]%
}{
    \end{enumerate}%
}

\newenvironment{Thing}{%
    \begin{enumerate}[label=Thing \arabic*,align=left, leftmargin=2.0cm]%
}{
    \end{enumerate}%
}




\begin{document}
\noindent
Bla, bla, here are the actions to do.


\begin{Action}
    \step
    Bla, bla, bla...

    \step
    Bla, bla, bla...

    \step
    Bla, bla, bla...
\end{Action}

\noindent
When the preceding actions have been done, you must do the following things.

\begin{Thing}
    \step
    Bla, bla, bla...

    \step
    Bla, bla, bla...

    \step
    Bla, bla, bla...
\end{Thing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use back returns in one item ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Are you referring to the indentation? Have updated the code so see if that is exactly what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks, that's great ! One last thing : is there a way to define a new environment like in my proposition ? It's only for semantic reasons.

Comment: @projetmbc: You could define a new environment, but the optional argument `[Action]` or `[Thing]` will have to be *after* the `steps` environment, as in `\begin{steps}[Action]`...

Comment: @PeterGrill: Using the [`xparse` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse), you could define `steps` using `\NewDocumentEnvironment{steps}{O{Action} O{,}}{..}{..}` which would default to `\begin{steps}[Action]`, but also allow for passing additional options to `enumerate` via a second optional argument: `\begin{steps}[Thing][topsep=5pt]`. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Have defined custom environments for you to keep the code as close as possible to what you have given in the MWE. Not that it is `\begin{Action}...\end{Action}` not `\begin[Action]{step}..\end{step}`

Comment: @Werner: Good suggestion, but I think it is simpler to just provide two environment as I have in the updated solution.

Comment: Thanks for all ! I'll try to have the feature I need (don't help me, it's time to me to use the indicatins of Werner, hoping that I'll not "break" my head...).

Answer (score 6):

```
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[{Action}~1:]
\item Blah
\item Blah blah
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[{Step}~1:]
\item Blah
\item Blah blah
\end{enumerate}
```