# The label of an enumerate list on its own line using enumitem

Tags: lists, enumitem

I would like to use the `enumitem` package to define a custom `enumerate` list such that the label occupies its own line.  An example would be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\Large\sc Assignment 1}\\[2ex]
\end{center}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\large\bf Problem \arabic*.},wide]

\item

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item First question.
    \item Second question.
\end{enumerate}

\item

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item First question.
    \item Second question.
\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

I would like the labels (Problem 1., Problem 2.) to appear on their own line, i.e., to force a line break right after the label.

According to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29517/forcing-new-line-after-item-number-in-enumerate-environment) putting `\mbox{}\\` after `\item` works, but I thought it could be possible to avoid that using features of `enumitem`.

Comment: Wow, all great answers!  Though I don't quite understand all that fancy etoolbox stuff, the one by Bernard was probably the most slick.  But I picked the one by Daniel Wunderlich because it seemed like the most direct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found anything like this at the `enumitem` documentation and I would also suggest daleif's answer using theorems.

But I was able to answer your question by redefining `\item` before a 1st level  `enumerate` environment and redefining it back to it's original definition after the environment. It also works with a simple `~`, you don't need a `\mbox{}` (maybe a `\mbox{}` has some advantages?).

I know this solution is bit dirty, but it leads to the desired result. Keep in mind that it affects *all* 1st level enumerations! Alternatively you could create a new list (see `enumitem` documentation).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}

\let\itemorig\item    % Create a copy of the original \item

\setlist[enumerate, 1]{%
  before=\renewcommand{\item}{\itemorig~},    % Append '~' to \item
  after=\renewcommand{\item}{\itemorig}       % Restore original \item
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\Large\sc Assignment 1}\\[2ex]
\end{center}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\large\bf Problem \arabic*.},wide]

\item

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item First question.
    \item Second question.
\end{enumerate}

\item

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item First question.
    \item Second question.
\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: Break after item of 1st level enumeration]

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be better not to make the `Problem ...` lists, but rather theorems. Then you do not have to add those "empty" items.

Using `ntheorem` we can also build the list configuration into the surrounding env:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theoremprework{
  \setlist*[enumerate]{label=(\alph*)} 
}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}


\begin{document}

\begin{problem}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item First question.
  \item Second question.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item First question.
  \item Second question.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{problem}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `enumitem` and `etoolbox`. I also  changed the centred ‘Assignment’s, manually numbered, to `sections`, automatically numbered and referable, with the `titlesec` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newenvironment{problems}{%
\apptocmd{\item}{\mbox{}}{}{}
\setlist[enumerate, 2]{wide}
%\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
\AtEndEnvironment{enumerate}{\vskip 1\baselineskip}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\large\bf Problem \arabic*.},wide]}%
{\end{enumerate}}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\filcenter\Large\scshape}{Assignment~\thesection}{0em}{\ifstrempty{#1}{}{: #1}}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}{2.5\baselineskip}%{}

\begin{document}

\section{}
\begin{problems}

\item

\begin{enumerate}
    \item First question.
    \item Second question.
\end{enumerate}

\item

\begin{enumerate}
    \item First question.
    \item Second question.
\end{enumerate}

\end{problems}

\section{}

\begin{problems}

\item

\begin{enumerate}
    \item First question.
    \item Second question.
\end{enumerate}

\item

\begin{enumerate}
    \item First question.
    \item Second question.
\end{enumerate}

\end{problems}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Start the *second level* **lists** with a empty item `\item[]` (`[]` is very important) or define a new list that do this like

```
\newenvironment{mylist}[1][]{\begin{enumerate}[#1]\item[]}{\end{enumerate}}
```

Thus, the normal space of the lists does not change and the options of the `enumitem` package can be used.

```
\begin{mylist}[<enumitem options>]
    \item First question.
    \item Second question.
\end{mylist}
```

My code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}

\begin{document}
\newenvironment{mylist}[1][]{\begin{enumerate}[#1]\item[]}{\end{enumerate}}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\large\bf Problem \arabic*.},wide]
\item
\begin{mylist}[(i)]
    \item First question.
    \item Second question.
\end{mylist}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

generates

> [image]

Comment: Very nice trick, but a minor criticism is this only works if every Problem has sub-parts. Well, indeed that was the case in the example, but it still makes the solution slightly less general IMHO.

Comment: In the Daniel Wunderlich's solution the  label **Problem** doesn't occupy its own line if the *item* begins with another text instead of an *enumerate* environment. It also leaves too much space before the first item.