# How is this kind of pseudocode written in latex?

Tags: algorithms

It doesn't seem to be formatted using instructions from the usual algorithm libraries of Latex.[image]

It seems to be simply formatted text, I am uncertain.

Comment: This looks like it's just nested enumerations. Getting the indentation aligned could be done with `enumitem`.

Comment: @AlanMunn can you write a sample latex code with a few nested random instructions in a similar manner to this.

Comment: The instructions look like math mode with a few `\textbf{n}` thrown in.

Comment: Each "Step x.y" is slightly indented compared to the text above. The author might have used nested tabulars.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to use the `enumitem` package to make nested lists. The trick of starting the list on a new line is adapted from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196074/2693).  This is not needed if every item contains some text, but is necessary if a step is embedded directly as an item of the list.  If a step will never be embedded like this, then the `before={\apptocmd{\item}{\mbox{}}{}{}}` code is not required.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newlist{algolist}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist*[algolist]{leftmargin=*,before={\apptocmd{\item}{\mbox{}}{}{}}}
\setlist*[algolist,1]{label={\itshape Step \arabic*:}}
\setlist*[algolist,2]{label={\itshape Step \arabic{algolisti}.\arabic*:}}
\setlist*[algolist,3]{label={\itshape Step \arabic{algolisti}.\arabic{algolistii}.\arabic*:}}
\begin{document}
\begin{algolist}
\item This is the first step of the algorithm. It can have many lines in it and they will wrap as you would expect. 
\item This is the second step of the algorithm.
    \begin{algolist}
    \item This is the first substep of the second step of the algorithm.
    \item This is the second substep of the second step of the algorithm.
        \begin{algolist}
        \item This is the first substep of the second substep of the algorithm.
        \item This is the second substep of the second substep of the algorithm.
        \end{algolist}
    \end{algolist}
\end{algolist}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: What's the `\mbox{}` for?

Comment: @egreg It's the trick used in answer I linked to to make a new level start on the next line. If there's a better way to do that, I'd be happy to use it.

Comment: It's not needed if every step has text before the substeps.

Comment: @egreg True, but I guess it's doing no harm, and will allow for the no text case, which is why I put it there.

Comment: @egreg I've added a bit more explanation.

Comment: I don't think it's needed for this case, even if a step starts with substeps, but that's up to the OP. I'd also add `noitemsep` at level 1 and `nosep` at levels 2 and 3, in order to match the picture.

Comment: @AlanMunn @egreg  Yes is not needed if every step has text, although an empty item can be written as `\item \mbox{}` by the user. It also affects somehow spacing, if you comment it out, you see the difference in 2.2.1 and 2.2.2 become one liners.