# Vertical spacing in enumitem list

Tags: spacing, enumitem

Consider the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

% New line after \item (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29518/15874)
\makeatletter
\def\myitem{%
  \@ifnextchar[ \@myitem{\@noitemargtrue\@myitem[\@itemlabel]}}
  \def\@myitem[#1]{\item[#1]\mbox{}\\}
\makeatother
% Exercise
\setlist[enumerate,1]{
  wide = 0\parindent,
  listparindent = 0pt,
  label = \textbf{Exercise~\arabic*}
}
% Question
\setlist[enumerate,2]{
  wide = 0\parindent,
  listparindent = 0pt,
  label = \textbf{\alph*)}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\myitem
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item A
    \item B
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

How do I

- remove the blank space after `Exercise`?
- get rid of the `Underfull \hbox` warning (do to the blank line after `Exercise`)? P.S. I don't want any text between `Exercise` and `a)`.

Comment: I think, the `\\ \` screws the spacing up ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That was too 'easy'; I should have figured that out myself. `:)` Thanks.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg If you want to start from a new line (which is what ``\mbox{}\\`` achieves) you can use `enumitem` keys for the occasion, see **3.7 Description styles** in the documentation.

Comment: @Manuel I might (read: probably) miss something obvious but I can't figure out which options to use. I think that I've tried all of them without succes. If I can make you give an answer with this behaviour, I will very much appreciate it.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I slipped, probably. That only works for `description`-like environments, and you are using `enumerate`.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: I wondered why you did not figure that yourself, but I thought that `strange` code for `myitem` stuff is really important

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the following line

```
\def\@myitem[#1]{\item[#1]\mbox{}\\}
```

you have `\\` which creates another line. Remove it to remove the blank space. If you want to further reduce the space you can add a negative vertical space. Here's the two versions.

### Output

**Added `\vspace{-1ex}`**

[image]

**Empty**

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

% New line after \item (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29518/15874)
\makeatletter
\def\myitem{%
  \@ifnextchar[ \@myitem{\@noitemargtrue\@myitem[\@itemlabel]}}
  \def\@myitem[#1]{\item[#1]\mbox{}\vspace{-1ex}}
\makeatother
% Exercise
\setlist[enumerate,1]{
  wide = 0\parindent,
  listparindent = 0pt,
  label = \textbf{Exercise~\arabic*},
  %partopsep=-40ex
}
% Question
\setlist[enumerate,2]{
  wide = 0\parindent,
  listparindent = 0pt,
  label = \textbf{\alph*)}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\myitem
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item A
    \item B
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That was rather 'easy'; I should probably have figured that out myself. `:)` Thanks.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg It's fine. :D I often don't see very plain mistakes in my code too. :D