# How can I suppress a page break in enumeration

Tags: latex-misc

I'm writing a document with some lists and I need to suppress a page break between the `\item` and the following line. Following is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[2]
line\\
line\\
line\\
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{Gruppe \arabic*},align=left,leftmargin=*,itemindent=0cm,labelwidth=\itemindent]
  \item~\\[-2em]
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\alph*)},align=left,leftmargin=-1cm]
    \item \blindtext

    \item \blindtext
  \end{enumerate}

  \item~\nopagebreak\\[-2em]\nopagebreak
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\alph*)},align=left,leftmargin=-1cm]
    \item \blindtext
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

I want `Gruppe 2` and `a) Lorem Ipsum` on the same page. A page break before the item or after the first line is ok. But the page breaks between the `\item` and the first line is a problem. I tried `\nopagebreak` but it doesn't change anything. I read about `samepage` environment or `minipage` but I think this is not possible in this situation. A manual page break is only the last solution since this is at many places in the document and I want to find some generic solution.

Comment: Did you see the posting [Unbreakable block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4471/5001)?

Comment: I can't create a block containing `\item` and only the first line of the paragraph. A page break after the first line of the paragraph is allowed. I only want to suppress a page break between these two lines.

Comment: Load the `needspace` package and issue the directive `\needspace{3\baselineskip}` immediately before the `\item~\\[-2em]` instruction in question.

Comment: @Mico formulate an answer and I will accept it. It is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you load the `needspace` package and employ its `\needspace` macro.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext,enumitem}
\usepackage{needspace} % <-- new

\begin{document}
\blindtext[2]
line\\
line\\
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{Gruppe \arabic*},
  align=left,leftmargin=*,itemindent=0cm,
  labelwidth=\itemindent]
  \item~\\[-1.25\baselineskip]
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\alph*)},
    align=left,leftmargin=-1cm]
    \item \blindtext
    \item \blindtext
  \end{enumerate}

  \needspace{3\baselineskip} % <-- new
  \item~\\[-1.25\baselineskip]
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\alph*)},
    align=left,leftmargin=-1cm]
    \item \blindtext
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still use a minipage in your case by utilizing the `reume` option for lists. This key is applied on second list, third list, and so on. Also notice that these `\item~\\[-2em]`s are not a recommended style. Use of hard `\\`s should be avoided, only in tabulars and sparingly in packages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[2]
line\\
line

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\noindent
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{Gruppe \arabic*},align=left,leftmargin=*]
  \item {}
  \item[] 
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\alph*)},align=left,leftmargin=-1cm]
    \item \blindtext
    \item \blindtext
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\noindent
\begin{enumerate}[resume,label=\textbf{Gruppe \arabic*},align=left,leftmargin=*]
  \item {}
  \item []
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\alph*)},align=left,leftmargin=-1cm]
    \item \blindtext
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But then I suppress the page break in the whole paragraph. That is not exactly what I want. I want to allow a page break in the paragraph but not between `Gruppe 2` and `a)`

Comment: And the use of `\item~\\[-2em]` was the only solution I found. It was recommended in this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29517/forcing-new-line-after-item-number-in-enumerate-environment. If you know a better way, I will listen.